# How to put link image to SQLite and display in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This is my small project, I can put name, address, and phone to SQLite and display it. And then I want to fill link image to the box and display an image in recyclerView. Please help!

Here's my app and code:

[RecyclerView display, no img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFNpT.png)

[And I want to fill the link image to this box... and img'll appear!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVbQu.png)

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Student> studentList;
    private StudentDatabase studentDatabase;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter();
        studentDatabase = new StudentDatabase(this);
        studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList = studentDatabase.getAll();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
        studentAdapter.setData(studentList);
        Student student = new Student();
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(studentList.size());

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateStudent.class);
                Student student = new Student();
                intent.putExtra("data", student);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 800);
            }
        });

        studentAdapter.setOnClickEvent(new StudentAdapter.OnClickEvent() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(int position) {
                Student student = studentList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModifyStudent.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", student);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 70);
            }

            @Override
            public void OnDelete(int position) {
                Student student = studentList.get(position);
                studentDatabase.delete(student.getId());
                studentList.remove(position);
                studentList = studentDatabase.getAll();
                studentAdapter.setData(studentList);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 70 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Student student = (Student) data.getSerializableExtra("returnData");
            studentDatabase.update(student);
            studentList = studentDatabase.getAll();
            studentAdapter.setData(studentList);
        }
        if (requestCode == 800 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            studentList = studentDatabase.getAll();
            studentAdapter.setData(studentList);
        }
    }
}
```

**Student.java:**

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private String img;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    public Student(String img, int id, String name, String address, String phone) {
        this.img = img;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public Student(){

    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

**CreateStudent.java:**

```
public class CreateStudent extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText createName, createAddress, creatPhone, createImage;
    private StudentDatabase studentDatabase;
    private Button btnCreate;
    private Button btnCancle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_student2);
        createName = findViewById(R.id.create_name);
        createAddress = findViewById(R.id.create_address);
        creatPhone = findViewById(R.id.create_phone);
        btnCreate = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
        btnCancle = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancle);
        createImage = findViewById(R.id.create_img);
        
        final Student student = new Student();
        if (student != null) {
            createName.setText(student.getName());
            createAddress.setText(student.getAddress());
            creatPhone.setText(student.getPhone());
        }
        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String cname = createName.getText().toString();
                String caddress = createAddress.getText().toString();
                String cphone = creatPhone.getText().toString();
                String cimage = createImage.getText().toString();
                if (cname.trim().equals("") || caddress.trim().equals("") || cphone.trim().equals("")) {
                    btnCreate.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    student.setName(cname);
                    student.setAddress(caddress);
                    student.setPhone(cphone);
                    student.setImg(cimage);
                    studentDatabase = new StudentDatabase(CreateStudent.this);
                    studentDatabase.addStudent(student);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("createData", student);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        btnCancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**StudentDatabase.java:**

```
public class StudentDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public StudentDatabase(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "STUDENT_DATABASE", null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE STUDENT(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STUDENT");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NAME", student.getName());
        cv.put("ADDRESS", student.getAddress());
        cv.put("PHONE", student.getPhone());

        db.insert("STUDENT", null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("STUDENT", " ID = " + id, null);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                String address = cursor.getString(2);
                String phone = cursor.getString(3);
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName(name);
                student.setId(id);
                student.setAddress(address);
                student.setPhone(phone);
                studentList.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return studentList;
    }

    public void update(Student student) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NAME", student.getName());
        cv.put("ADDRESS", student.getAddress());
        cv.put("PHONE", student.getPhone());
        db.update("STUDENT", cv, "ID = " + student.getId(), null);

    }

}
```

**StudentAdapter.java:**

```
public class StudentAdapter<extend> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Student> studentList;
    private OnClickEvent onClickEvent;

    public void setOnClickEvent(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
        this.onClickEvent = onClickEvent;
    }

    public StudentAdapter() {
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Student> listData) {
        if (studentList == null) {
            studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        studentList.clear();
        studentList.addAll(listData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StudentAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Student student = studentList.get(position);
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(studentList.get(position).getImg()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.name.setText(student.getName());
        holder.address.setText(student.getAddress());
        holder.phone.setText(student.getPhone());

        holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onClickEvent != null) {
                    onClickEvent.OnDelete(position);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onClickEvent != null) {
                    onClickEvent.OnItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name, address, phone;
        private Button btn_delete, btn_edit;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            btn_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            btn_edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        }
    }

    public interface OnClickEvent {
        void OnItemClick(int position);

        void OnDelete(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your `StudentAdapter` class? There is where you define what to be displayed on your RecyclerView item.

Comment: sorry my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have correctly defined your recyclerView with Glide library to show the picture but you are not storing(saving) picture information in your database.

```java
public void addStudent(Student student) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NAME", student.getName());
        cv.put("ADDRESS", student.getAddress());
        cv.put("PHONE", student.getPhone());

        db.insert("STUDENT", null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

you should have something like

```java
cv.put("PICTURE", student.getImg());
```

you should also do the same for your `public void update(Student student)` method for storing(saving) user picture. And also with your `public void addStudent(Student student)` method definition. And also you should retrieve your picture information inside your `

```java
public ArrayList<Student> getAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                String address = cursor.getString(2);
                String phone = cursor.getString(3);
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName(name);
                student.setId(id);
                student.setAddress(address);
                student.setPhone(phone);
                studentList.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return studentList;
    }
```

something like this:

```java
String picture = cursor.getString(4);

student.setImg(picture);
```

The picture information should be the path of the picture location which might be a URL or a file location in your phone's disk.

...............
updates:

```java
String query = "CREATE TABLE STUDENT(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE INTEGER, PICTURE TEXT)";
```

Comment: do i need to create sqlite column IMAGE and type TEXT or BLOB ?

Comment: @HaMinhDuong TEXT is enough since you're going to store the path string. You're not storing the image itself. So use TEXT.

Comment: now i have error: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.  At"String image = cursor.getString(4)"

Comment: @HaMinhDuong You should drop your previous data and try to insert again. Since you haven't made any migration your database has the old schema. Therefore please clear your app data by un installing your app and trying to install again. Then you have to make sure you have added your data first. You should `addStudent` first before calling `getAll`

Comment: Lol it's so easy haha thank you so much my friend :D

Comment: yea its work too smooth and i'll add more feature to my book, hope to see u

Comment: @HaMinhDuong glad I helped!

Comment: @NadimAnsari how ?

Comment: Please check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/332508) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/332508). Simple the tick icon on the left top side of my answer. @HaMinhDuong

Comment: oh cool, thank you for checking my grammar =))